# JTextField object creation fails

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am getting the below exception when I initialize using below declaration:
`private final JTextField tcpPortField = new JTextField("5015");`

**There is a main class **DeviceSimulator** main() has a call:**

```
final StartDialog startDialog = new StartDialog();
        startDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Now within StartDialog I have :

```
private final JTextField tcpPortField = new JTextField("5015");`
```

This is the line where I get below exception. I have tested with enabling Debugger in Ecliplse and certainly it is failing at the above line

This is really strange I am trying to run an existing project and I am stuck at it. However If I simply right some code with same `JTextField` initialization in a new project I don't see any exception. I am stuck at it from past few days. Any help is greately appreciated. I am using 1.7 JDK.

**The Exception Thrown is:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getTabbedTextWidth(Utilities.java:273)
    at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getTabbedTextWidth(Utilities.java:208)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainView.getLineWidth(PlainView.java:669)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainView.updateDamage(PlainView.java:567)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainView.insertUpdate(PlainView.java:451)
    at javax.swing.text.FieldView.insertUpdate(FieldView.java:293)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1602)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1861)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:202)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:749)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:708)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:670)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1718)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.<init>(JTextField.java:243)
```

Comment: It's not from this line.

Comment: please share your `main` method code, nothing seems wrong here, and you have this error in you `main`

Comment: please post the code.

Comment: I don't have JDK 7 code but from [GrepCode OpenJDK 1.7.0_40 javax.swing.text.Utilities.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/swing/text/Utilities.java/) it seems line 273 is this: `nextX += metrics.charsWidth(txt, i - charCount, charCount);` which suggests either the font metrics are null or there's a problem with the text. Did you change the font in your project?

Comment: Thanks all .I have added more info to the post.  I am certain that code fails at this point as I am running with debugger on and it is Throwing exception at this line.@Thomas . I am using an existing project . I am not sure what do you mean by change font to the project. Please explain if possible. Thanks

Comment: Start with a "find in files" (ctrl shift f) for the word "Font" and see what comes up.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I can see : UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getDefaults()
    .put("defaultFont", "SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf"); Is this creating any issues?

Comment: This might be the cause for that issue, yes. Try without that and if it works then you at least have a direction for your investigation.

Comment: @Thomas It is working if I comment this.Thanks.But wanted to know if I want to lead these fonts where should these .ttf be present any Ideas?

Comment: They should be present int you project resources folder and you should load them like any other file.